# datetimepicker for jquery like silverlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverlight, datetimepicker

I need to edit date and time separately, like this [link](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Silverlight-Making-a-DateTimePicker.aspx). i'm going to create a application in jquery which need to edit date and time like in silverlight datetimepicker so i'm in need of datetimepicker like the above link. Which is date and time should be edited separately but after that edit it should show that date and time in the same Textbox.

Answer (score 0):

**use bootstrap or jQuery UI** 
simply download  and include the script from jquery website

jqueryui.com/download/

then

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>


<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a lot of jquery plugins available as datetime picker.

> http://umcdatetimepicker.codeplex.com/
>
> http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/
>
> http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/timestamp.shtml
>
> http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCalendar/